# Why does f.submit not generate an id attribute in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I had an issue where the following jquery script was failing in Rails 3.1 due to it not finding the element.

jquery

```
member_submit_button = $("#member_submit");
```

haml

```
= form_for @member do |f|
...
    f.submit "Update details", :class => "member_submit_button bluebutton"
```

In Rails 3.0 this works fine, and I tracked it down to Rails 3.1 not generating the id attribute. In rails 3.0 a tag id = "member_submit".

This of course is easily fixed by adding the :id => "member_submit" parameter to the f.submit call. But I wanted to know what the reason was for this change as I have not seen this documented anywhere.

Comment: Have you passed the form in as `f`? For example `<%= form_for @member do |f| %>`

Comment: Sorry, incomplete example. I have edited to include the do |f|. The submit button is being created in both 3.0 and 3.1, just not the id attribute in 3.1

Comment: check the git blame log and commit log for the file change and then look at the commit message on github to see the reasoning behind it.

Comment: Can't see anything in either [tag_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfcef34bb54bce0cda77da4ae99774fa501ab713/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb) or [form_tag_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cfcef34bb54bce0cda77da4ae99774fa501ab713/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I upgraded from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 and noticed one of my specs failing due to the same missing ID attribute. 
A bit of googling revealed that this is an expected behaviour for Rails 3.1, as specified in the respective [Release Notes (see sect. "5.3 - Action View")](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html):

> The submit form helper does not generate an id “object_name_id” anymore.

Even if my message doesn't answer your question entirely, as I can't tell you why the Rails team decided to make this change, at least you can be sure that that's not a Rails defect, but rather a change in that form helper. ;)