# getting automatic id's for submit tags back in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to move an app to rails 3.1. Many of my tests break, because the submit buttons no longer have an id.  the [Release Notes (see sect. "5.3 - Action View")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238512/why-does-f-submit-not-generate-an-id-attribute-in-rails-3-1) confirm it:

> The submit form helper does not generate an id “object_name_id” anymore.

Here's the [relevant commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d3cfee118245a8806436bbf904bbad36dd810012) that changed action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb.

I want have the old behaviour back without messing with the installed gem or changing all my views by hand. So I try to monkey patch it:

```
# this is config/initializers/FormHelperMonkeypatch.rb

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper # <-- this is the line phoet repaired, see his answer below

      # code from rails 3.0
      def submit(value=nil, options={})
        value, options = nil, value if value.is_a?(Hash)
        value ||= submit_default_value
        @template.submit_tag(value, options.reverse_merge(:id => "#{object_name}_submit"))
      end

    end
  end
end
```

I restarted my server, but I see no effect of my patch.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are editing the wrong place. use this:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    class FormBuilder
      # code from rails 3.0
      def submit(value=nil, options={})
        value, options = nil, value if value.is_a?(Hash)
        value ||= submit_default_value
        @template.submit_tag(value, options.reverse_merge(:id => "#{object_name}_submit"))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks!  s/module FormHelper/class FormBuilder/ solved my problem!